# How to check if an entry in a column exists

Tags: sql

I want to check if an entry in my column name exists.

But every time I try something with "if" or "if exists" it gives me a syntax error.

(select 1 from class101 WHERE name = 'Peter')

Works and returns me "1 row in set"

(select 1 from class101 WHERE name = 'Peter123')

Works and returns me "Empty set"

Now I want to insert something if it doesn´t exist.

```
if not exists (select 1 from class101 where name = 'Peter123')

BEGIN 

insert into class101 values ('Peter123')

END;
```

This gives me a syntax error

I hope someone can help me find the error.

Comment: Specify the column name in the insert. INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);

Comment: That is what WHERE conditions are for

Comment: Which DBMS are you asking this for? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? PostgreSQL? ...

Comment: If you want the column `name` to be unique in the table, then create a unique constraint on the column. Then insert, and it will succeed if the name is new or fail otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM class101 WHERE name="Peter123";

this will return number of exists Peter123.

Answer (score 0):

The column name must be enclosed in brackets because it is a reserved word in sql, so try:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 from class101 where [name] = 'Peter123')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO class101 VALUES ('Peter123')
END;
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: Works like a escape, is necessary if the column name is a reserved keyword on SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

you have unique key constraint on that column for that table. so that only one such value can be inserted into that column,
else if you want to solve by sql single command,

```
insert into class101  (select '''PETER''' from dual where not exists (select 1 from class101 where name like 'PETER'));
```

else by plsql:

```
declare
l_flag varchar2(2) := 'N';
begin
select 'Y' into l_flag from class101 where name='PETER' and rownum=1;
if l_flag = 'Y'
then
insert into class101 values ('PETER');
end if;
exception
when no_data_found
then
null;
end;
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.